# How can PowerShell automatically answer an on-screen prompt from Outlook when sending an email?

Tags: powershell, outlook

When sending emails to addresses outside of my organization, I have to click an "Allow" button from the on-screen prompt to confirm that I am not sending the message to an address outside of my organization by mistake (this is essentially a security check by my organization).

Now, I am looking for a PowerShell solution that will automatically answer the on-screen prompt (which is pushed through by Outlook) as "Allow" - to enable the email to be automatically sent to a client on a scheduled basis.

I have the following very basic PowerShell script which will get right up to the point of sending the email, but the actual send itself will get blocked by the security check shown in the image below.  Of course, if I click "Allow", the email will send.  But is there anyway to automatically answer the security check on-screen prompt as "Allow"?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "receiver@gmail.com" 
$Mail.Subject = "subject" 
$Mail.Body = "testing"
$Mail.Attachments.Add("C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\data.csv")
$Mail.Send()
###All good up to here -- but then the security check.  Is there a PowerShell way to answer this prompt as "Allow"?
```

[image: On Screen Prompt]

Comment: I'm sure there's some way to have it not prompt for that and just do it but, you can always try to send keys to the prompt.

Comment: This shows how to use C# to use windows UI automation to work with outlook. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/75bf4e62-b459-4bf6-976c-33feb450e36a/how-to-create-ui-automation-for-outlook-2007-using-c-net-30using-systemwindowsautomation?forum=windowsaccessibilityandautomation

Comment: Is that the native Outlook security prompt or a message box shown by some custom addin that only watches emails to the outside recipients?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the dialog message comes from an Outlook add-in. In that case you can disable the add-in before sending and then return it back by setting the `Connect` property of the `COMAddin` class.

Find the add-in in the `Application.COMAddins` collection by using the `Description`, `ProgId`, or `Guid` properties, then set the `COMAddin.Connect` property to false to disable it.

Keep in mind that that you can only disable/enable add-ins installed in HKCU. The ones installed in HKLM can only be modified by the admin.